# Solve $x^{\frac{1}{x}}=0$

Tags: exponentiation

When answering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116112/find-the-maximum-of-fx-x1-x) question, I contemplated across the following problem:

> Find $x$ such that $x^{\frac{1}{x}}=0.$

I thought RHS $ = 0$ is a special case, so I attempted solving $$\frac{1}{x} \ln x = \ln c$$ from some constant $c > 0,$ but I do not know how. I heard about Lambert W, but I am not familiar with it.

BTW, Maple `solve(x^(1/x) = 0)` gives $x=0$, and [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E%281%2Fx%29+%3D%3D+0) gives `(no solution exist)`!

How can I solve this?

Comment: To solve $\ln x = cx$, you need to reach for far more advanced tools than basic ones; you need [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_W_function).

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the solution to $$\frac{1}{x} \ln x = \ln c$$ using Lambert's W is $$x = e^{-W(-\ln c)}.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way you can ever have $a^b=0$ is to have $a=0$, but in the current case this leads to $0^{1/0}$, which is undefined. So, there's no solution.

Comment: However, $\lim_{x\to0}x^\frac1x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The functin $f(x)=x^{1/x}=\exp(\frac{1}{x}\log x)$ never *equals* zero, however the limit as $x\to 0^+$ evaluates to zero, so if we consider the domain $[0,\infty)$ we could remove the discontinuity at $x=0$ if we desired.