# Solution to $x^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0$ using Lambert's W?

Tags: exponentiation

> In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116138/solve-x-frac1x-0), I learned that the equation
>   $$x^{\frac{1}{x}} = c$$
>   have no solutions when $c = 0$. Below, I tried using [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_W_function), and I found a solution at $x = 0$. Did I make a mistake?

If $x^{\frac{1}{x}} = c$ then $${\frac{1}{x}}\ln x = \ln c$$ Let $x = e^{-y}$. So $${\frac{1}{x}}\ln x = -y e^{y} = \ln c$$ The solution of $y e^y = -\ln c$ using Lambert's W is $$ y = W(-\ln c).$$
Hence $$ x = e^{-W(-\ln c)} $$ is a solution of $x^{\frac{1}{x}} = c$. Now, to solve $x^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0$, I tried $$ x = \lim_{c\to 0} e^{-W(-\ln c)} = 0,$$
since $\lim -\ln c \to \infty$ as $c\to 0$, and $\lim W(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$.

Hence, $x = 0$ is a solution to $x^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0$. But this contradicts the answers I got for my previous question. I must've made a mistake. Please point out where.

Comment: Didn't anon point out in your previous question that (limitwise, from above) $x = 0$ is indeed a solution? So this does not contradict that.

Comment: @TMM $x \to 0^+$ is a solution, which not my case here.

Comment: If $c=0$ then $\ln(c)$ is undefined.

Comment: So, you claim $0^{1/0}$ is defined?

Comment: @GEdgar is your question for me or Patrick?

Comment: The question is for whoever says $x=0$ is a solution for $x^{1/x} = 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar No. I did not claim that $0^{1/0}$ is defined. My question is asking to *locate the mistake* in the steps above while using Lambert's W. Gerry's answer fully answered it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write, $x=e^{-y}$, you have ruled out $x=0$ as a solution, since there's no such $y$.