# find the largest no among these

Tags: real-analysis

$1,2^{1/2},3^{1/3},4^{1/4},\dotsc $

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE !  Please share your efforts in solving this problem otherwise it is likely to get closed

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/758700/321264

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ has a maximum point at $e$ in $(0,+\infty)$. Consider the derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{x^{1/x}(1-\ln(x))}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Here not f(x)....it is f(n)=n^(1÷n)

Comment: @sasanka jana Yes, but the derivative says that $f$ is increasing in $(0,e)$ and decreasing in $(e,+\infty)$. So $f(1)<f(2)$ and $f(3)>f(4)>f(5)>\cdots$. So the maximum is $f(2)=2^{1/2}$ or $f(3)=3^{1/3}$. Raising to the 6th power you find easily that $8<9$ implies that $2 ^{1/2} < 3^{1/3}$. By the way, I gave only a hint in my answer...

Comment: Again lim n^{1/n}=1 as n tends to infinity

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^{1/x}$ has a unique maximum
at $x=e$,
the only possibilities are
$2$ and $3$.

Since
$2^3 < 3^2$,
$2^{1/2} < 3^{1/3}$,
the maximum is at $x=3$.