# Prove that $x^y < y^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, inequality

Assuming that $e<y<x$, prove that $ x^y < y^x$.

I think this must be easy, but I can't work it out. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: $$x^y<y^x\iff x^{1/x}<y^{1/y}$$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116112/find-the-maximum-of-fx-x1-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

This is equivalent to $y\ln x<x\ln y$, i.e. since $x, y>0$, to 
$$\frac{\ln x}x<\frac{\ln y}y.$$

Set $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}x$ and determine the variations of $f$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

take logs to compare $x \ln y ? y \ln x$ or equivalently $\frac{x}{\ln x} ? \frac{y}{\ln y}$ (sign does not change since $\ln x > \ln y > 1$) and look at the function $x/\ln x$ to see if it's increasing or decreasing for $x > e$