# Solve the system of equations $x^y=y^x$

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, exponentiation

Solve the system of equations
$$
x^y=y^x \\
a^x=b^y
$$

I could not solve this despite many tries

Comment: What kind of numbers are $x$, $y$, $a$, $b$? And you mean exponentiation and not exclusive or?

Comment: um nothing mentioned like that ...

Comment: It's not quite what your asking, but there may be some useful leads in here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705754/xy-yx-prove-that-xyee/1711556#1711556

Comment: i tried by taking log on both sides and further tried to simplify it

Comment: $a,b$ are considered as real constants?

Comment: jim i think it can be done more easily that the leads provided in your link :D

Comment: MathematicianByMistake nothing given in the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are looking for solutions where $x,y,a,b$ are positive, none equal to $1$. Furthermore, that $a\neq b$. [If $a=b$, then any pair $y=x$ is a solution.] The equations can be rearranged to

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
y\ln(x)&=x\ln(y)\\
y&=x\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}=cx
\end{aligned}\right.$$
where $c=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}\neq1$. Substituting $y$ from the second into the first:
$$
\begin{align}
&&cx\ln(x)&=x\ln(cx)\\
\implies&& c\ln(x)&=\ln(cx)\\
\implies&& x^c&=cx\\
\implies&& x^{c-1}&=c\\
\end{align}
$$
If $c$ is negative (that is, if $a,b$ are on opposite sides of $1$), there are no solutions. Otherwise, if $a,b$ are on the same side of $1$, then $x=c^{1/(c-1)}$ and:

$$\begin{align}
x&=\left(\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}\right)^{1\left/\left(\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}-1\right)\right.}=\sqrt[\log_b(a)-1]{\log_b(a)}\\
y&=cx=\left(\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}\right)^{1\left/\left(1-\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}\right)\right.}=\sqrt[1-\log_a(b)]{\log_b(a)}
\end{align}$$