# Determine the Largest Number in the Infinite Sequence

Tags: inequality

> Determine the largest number in the infinite sequence
>
> $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[4]{4},....\sqrt[n]{n}$.

I found $3^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is largest.

I am confused how to start the question. Please help me

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116112/find-the-maximum-of-fx-x1-x

Comment: consider the function $$f(x)=x^{1/x}$$

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[e]{e}$ is the largest. BTW, this question has been asked here approximately $200$ times.

Comment: Are you considering $n\in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ for $x \ge 1$. Show, by using the derivative, that $f$ attaines a global maximum at $x=e$. Hence $f$ is increasing on $[1,e]$ and decreasing on $[e, \infty)$. Since $2<e<3$ amd $1 <\sqrt{2}<\sqrt[3]{3}$ we have  $\sqrt[3]{3}>\sqrt[n]{n}$ for $n \ge 4$

Answer (score 2):

If we find the derivative of the continuous function $y=x^\frac 1 x$ we get:

\begin{align}
\ln y&=\frac 1 x \ln x\\
\frac 1 y \frac{\text dy}{\text dx}&=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}\\
\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}&=\frac{x^\frac 1 x(1 - \ln x)}{x^2}
\end{align}

Setting this to zero, we get:

$$1-\ln x = 0\\x=e$$

Since you have presented a discrete function, $e$ is not in the domain. However, $e$ is closest to 3.