# Relation between $x^{x+1}$ and $(x+1)^{x}$, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, integers

So say that we have a pair $(x^{x+1},(x+1)^{x})$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Is there any correlation between the members of this pair? Or are they not related?

Comment: In the positives, both functions are invertible, the relation is immediate.

Comment: We need the  trichotomy  $$(x+1)^{1/x+1} >=< x^{1/x}$$   Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116112/find-the-maximum-of-fx-x1-x

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by *correlation*? Otherwise this question is so broad as to be unsuited for exact analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio $\frac{(x+1)^x}{x^{x+1}}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{(x+1)^x}{x^{x}}=\frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$

As $x$ gets large, $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x \rightarrow e$, so the ratio gets close to $\frac{e}{x}$ which itself gets closer to $0$ as $x$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of interpreting Keith Blackman's answer above is that:

(x+1)^x>x^(x+1) ---(1)

Above equation (1) attains equality at x~2.2932

But 'x' above is not an integer.

There is a equation which has integer solution shown below.

x^y=y^x

Above has solution, (x,y)=(4,2)